# convert string in mysql DB to an array

Tags: php, mysql

the code shown below performs an mysql query using implode() to search for multiple variables in one expression, which i like:

```
<?
include("connect.php"); // file to connect to db

$states = array('CA','CO','TX');
$states_str = implode("','", $states);

$query="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE state IN ('$states_str')";

$result=mysql_query ($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['state'];
}
?>
```

but i have run into a new issue. as you can see from the above 'states' is hard-coded.

i want the user to be able to select the states they want to pull, have that choice saved to a separate table in the DB, and then have that list read into the 'states' array shown above. Something like this:

```
<?
include("connect.php"); // file to connect to db

$sql_gs="SELECT states_c FROM states WHERE id='1'";
$result_gs=mysql_query($sql_gs);
$row_gs = mysql_fetch_row($result_gs);
$gcs = $row_gs[0];

$states = array($gcs);
$states_str = implode("','", $states);

$query="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE state IN ('$states_str')";

$result=mysql_query ($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['state'];
}
?>
```

but this code throws an error.

what is saved to the states table noted above, and what is contained in the states_c field, a VARCHAR field, is this:

```
'CA','CO,'TX'
```

so the '$gcs' variable in the code above ...

```
echo $gcs; // result 'CA','CO,'TX'
```

in other words, the *text* of $gca (for 'get chosen states') is *exactly* the same as the text in the hard-coded version above that works

but when i try to place the results of the $gca variable, the exact same text, i get an error, no data is pulled, because in this statement

```
    $states = array($gcs); // $gcs reads exactly as 'CA','CO,'TX'
```

the data is not read, whereas in this one

```
    $states = array('CA','CO,'TX');
```

the states are recognized and the code fires.

what is the issue with trying to place the same text in this line of code via a named variable as opposed to 'spelling it out' in a hard coded fashion?

TIA

===================

UPDATE

I tried this:

```
<?
include("connect.php"); // file to connect to db

$sql_gs="SELECT states_c FROM states WHERE id='1'";
$result_gs=mysql_query($sql_gs);
$row_gs = mysql_fetch_row($result_gs);
$gcs = $row_gs[0];

$states = explode("','", $gcs); // replaces $states = array('CA','CO','TX');
$states_str = implode("','",$states);

$query="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE state IN ('$states_str')";

$result=mysql_query ($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
//echo $row['mail_state']; 
}

?>
```

but still no result ...

Comment: You shouldn't be storing a delimited list in a string field anyway, it should be a relationship in the db.

Comment: in order for the user to pull the data from a list of states the user selects, they have to input that data somewhere. 'States Desired > ___________' user types in, 'CA, CO,TX' ... that choice is stored in a table. but no matter where the data goes, it is still a string of characters that will be gathered up in a variable with a '$' sign in front of it, and when i go from $states = array('CA',CO','TX') to $states = array($var), or however you say it, the code breaks, irrespective of where $var comes from, bcz i need the query to search all the states the user wants. thanks for the reply

Comment: Rather than typing a list of states, let them select from a select box. That's what it's for.

Comment: the issue is searching for multiple states in a single query. no matter how the user selects the states, that selection will have the data contained in a variable , ie $states = array($var) instead of having it hardcoded and spelled out, ie $states = array('CA','CO','TX') -- the problem is how to read the contents of the $var to make the code work as if it has been hardcoded and spelled out. why $query="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE state IN ('$states_str')" will not work with array($var) but will with array('CA',CO','TX') is the question

Comment: Again - if you store the data in the database properly, this is not an issue. You would simply do a JOIN. You should never store data in a delimited list, that's not what a relational database is for.

Comment: i understand your point. but the issue is wherever the data comes from, i need all the records in the states the user selects to be pulled from the DB. at some point, all those states are going to be assembled into a variable. and then i want to fit that into a single query expression, eg $query="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE state = ('ALL THE STATES THE USER SELECTED ONE WAY OR THE OTHER HERE')", instead of $query="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE state ='CA' OR state = 'CO' OR state = 'TX'"; -- thanks for the reply, but i dont think you understand the question.

Comment: Are you actually missing the closing quote between CO and TX? Look at the highlighting?

Comment: And I don't think you understand my answer. You would never do ""SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE state ='CA' OR state = 'CO' OR state = 'TX'";" You would do a JOIN.  AS IN: SELECT * FROM table1 t INNER JOIN userSelection u ON u.stateID = t.stateID.

If you had tried it instead of insisting it won't work for you, maybe you'd be done by now.

Answer (score 0):

Use explode.

```
$states = explode(",",$gcs);
```

Hmm. After looking at your implode statement.  you may actually need:

```
$states = explode("','",$gcs);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: thank you for your reply. the code still throws an error. please see my updated post above.